# how to loop through a 2d array in pointers notation and array notation

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers

I am new to c++ so I am asking kind of a simple question, but i cant seem to find the answer.
I am trying to write a function that will print all of the elements of a two dimensional integer array and print its contents. i am trying to do it using array notation using pointer notation. i dont know what to send in to the method of the pointer notation. this is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void arrayNotation(int array[][4], int row){
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            cout << array[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cin.get();
}
void pointerNotation(){//i dont know what to send it
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<4; j++){
            cout << (*(*(array + i) + j));
        }
    }

}
int main(){     
    int array[2][4] = { { 467, 223, 189, 100 }, { 222, 561, 489, 650 } };
    arrayNotation(array, 2);
    pointerNotation();//how do you send it in to be pointer notation?

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is

```
void pointerNotation(int (*array)[4]) // pass pointer to array-of-4 ints
```

But the above is really the same as `int array[][4]`, as the latter is just syntactic sugar.

Note that you cannot do

```
void pointerNotation(int**)
```

as `int[][4]` does not decay to `int**`. The latter is more flexible, the former is just a pointer to arrays-of-4-ints.

Comment: when you say "But the above is really the same as int array[][4], as the latter is just syntactic sugar." , what do you mean? it is the same just in pointer notation? also how is (*array)[4] a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: `int*` is the same as `int[]` when used as a type of a function parameter. Similarly, `int (*array)[4]` is a notation for a pointer to a variable of type `int[4]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of 4 ints, and the syntactic sugar for it is just `int array[][4]`. If you increment the pointer, then you "jump" over 4 elements, so basically it represents a 2D array. That is, `*(array+i)` points to the `i`-th row, so further dereferencing it `*(*(array+i)+j)` is the element located at position `[i][j]` in the 2D array.

Comment: oh i get that.  so by  putting in int (*array)[4] - is that what is making it pointer notation ?

Comment: @programmingGirl yes, it explicitly uses the pointer notation. But again, internally there is no difference. It is exactly the same situation as when writing `f(int*)` and `f(int[])`. Both are completely equivalent declarations.

Comment: thank you so much. this works. so by me doing it the array notation and the pointer notation, i get the same answer. but in theory what exactly is the difference?

Comment: @programmingGirl there is no difference, even in theory. The notation is equivalent. The compiler translates it to exactly the same assembler code. Try finding a good documentation about pointers, arrays, pointers to arrays, and arrays of pointers. In other words, make sure you understand what is the difference between `int*`, `int arr[4]`, `int (*arr)[4]` and `int* arr[4]`.

Comment: also, why dont we need to send the array in with the & by the main? when you say  "using pointer notation only" it doesnt mean also using the &?

Comment: when you pass the name of the array, you implicitly pass a pointer to the first element. So in this case `f(array)` is the same as `f(&array[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to explicitly pass the number of rows and the number of columns. That way, one approach might be the following.

```
void pointerNotation(const int * const pArray, const int ROWS, const int COLS) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            const int offset = i * ROWS + j;
            cout << *(pArray + offset);   // or pArray[offset]
        }
    }
}
```

Call as

```
pointerNotation(array, 2, 4);
```

Comment: but i dont think we are supposed to use const. we need to do  using pointer notation only

Comment: `const` guarantees that the values are readonly, it is unrelated to pointers. You can omit them if you want, for this question, it does not make a difference.

Comment: This is an alternative approach indeed, but is using a "flat" array. Perhaps this is what @programmingGirl wants though.

Comment: i get that. my question though is, because you sent in the row and col you only needed to do int * pArray and not int * pArray[4]?

Comment: Yes, `int * pArray` is sufficient. As @vsoftco mentioned, in this approach, we are *flattening* a 2D-array to a 1D one. As a matter of fact, computer memory is linear, this is how a 2D array is stored in memory.

Comment: oh, interesting. that makes a lot of sense. thank you for teaching me this.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup 2D arrays and send them 2 different ways too.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void pointerNotation(int (*array)[4]){//i dont know what to send it
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<4; j++){
            cout << (*(*(array + i) + j)) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

void pointerNotation2(int **array){//i dont know what to send it
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<4; j++){
            cout << (*(*(array + i) + j)) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(){     
    int array[2][4] = { { 467, 223, 189, 100 }, { 222, 561, 489, 650 } };

    int **array2 = new int*[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        *(array2 + i) = new int[4];
    }

    // copying for second array
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            *(*(array2 + i) + j) = *(*(array + i) + j);
        }
    }

    pointerNotation(array);

    pointerNotation2(array2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
467 223 189 100 
222 561 489 650 
467 223 189 100 
222 561 489 650
```